# Set focus in Shiny app to a specific UI element on load

Tags: r, shiny

After my R Shiny app has loaded, I would like to set focus to the `selectInput` element, so that the user can immediately select an item by up-down arrows and hit enter.

I was trying to capture the JavaScript `load` event, send it to R and than use the `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` to set focus of the `selectInput` element.

As an intermediate step, I was also trying, to use the click event from an `actionButton` to trigger the element focus. Although I think most parts should be in the code, the `load` event does not get transmitted to the server and the focus part does get picked up by JavaScript.

This post [focusing the cursor in textArea after clicking an action button in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362861) also did not help me enough to get it to the finish line.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script('
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
      alert("Loaded");
      Shiny.setInputValue("loaded", 1) // new identical function to Shiny.onInputChange
    });
 ')),
  tags$head(tags$script('
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("focus", function(null) {
      document.getElementById("select").focus()
    });  
 ')),
  headerPanel("Focus",  windowTitle = "Focus"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, class = "panel",
           selectInput("select", label = "Your Choice", choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2"), selectize = TRUE),
           actionButton("click", "Click")
    ),
    column(width = 10,
           textOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$loaded, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("focus",list(NULL))
    print("Loaded")
  })

  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print("Selected")
  })

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("focus",list(NULL))
    print("Clicked")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the console (Ctrl+Shift+i with Chrome), you will see there are some errors in your JS code.

The main one is that `shiny` is not ready yet when you open the app, so the function `Shiny.setInputValue` is not found.

To be sure `shiny` is ready, use:

```js
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(){
  ......
});
```

Now, after some multiple trials, I found that the element to be "focused" is not the entire `select` element. It is its `div` subelement with class `selectize-input`, that you can select with `$("#select ~ .selectize-control > .selectize-input")`.

Finally, the good action to perform is not `focus`, it is `click`. Here is the full app:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(){
  alert("Loaded");
  Shiny.setInputValue("loaded", 1);
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("focus", function(x){
    $("#select ~ .selectize-control > .selectize-input").click();
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  headerPanel("Focus",  windowTitle = "Focus"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, class = "panel",
           selectInput("select", label = "Your Choice", 
                       choices = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2"), selectize = TRUE),
           actionButton("click", "Click")
    ),
    column(width = 10,
           textOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$loaded, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("focus", list(NULL))
    print("Loaded")
  })

  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print("Selected")
  })

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("focus", list(NULL))
    print("Clicked")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I was looking at the inspector for the elements but the console for the errors is of cause also very useful to look at.

Comment: Too bad that the `selected` is not working. It would be great if the event would already fire when moving the up/down keys in the `selectInput` without even hitting the enter key...

Comment: There is actually a `$("#select).change()` event too... but I don't get that to fire off.

Comment: FYI, the `$("#select).change()` event works too when I deactivate the `selectize` option in the `selectInput` element, i.e. if I set `selectize = FALSE`. When the item is selected once, each following move up or down by the mouse fires another change-event!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/stéphane-laurent I was unable to adapt your solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76607795/set-focus-on-textinput-on-load @stéphane-laurent