# How to set a focus on textInput on load in Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I was unable to adapt the code on  [Set focus in Shiny app to a specific UI element on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252694/set-focus-in-shiny-app-to-a-specific-ui-element-on-load) to set the focus on a `textInput` on page load.
My last try:

```
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(){
  alert("Loaded");
  Shiny.setInputValue("loaded", 1);
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("focus", function(x){
    $("#select ~ .input-control > .input").click();
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  headerPanel("Focus",  windowTitle = "Focus"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, class = "panel",
           textInput("spot", "spot"),
           actionButton("click", "Click")
    ),
    column(width = 10,
           textOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$loaded, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("focus", list(NULL))
    print("Loaded")
  })

  observeEvent(input$select, {
    print("Selected")
  })

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("focus", list(NULL))
    print("Clicked")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `textInput` has `inputId` "spot", hence you have to replace this inside the `JS`. Additionally, in case of a `textInput` it suffices to use `select()`.

```
js <- '
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(){
  alert("Loaded");
  Shiny.setInputValue("loaded", 1);
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("focus", function(x){
    $("#spot").select();
    Shiny.setInputValue("select", 1);
  });
});
'
```

[image]

Comment: I replaced `js` in previous code but it still does not set focus on textInput